# Database will not display results?

Tags: java, database, jframe

In my Java program I'm having trouble running a `Addplaylist.java` file. It opens up fine...But for me to be able to `add a playlist` I will need the names of each `member` from the Database!

I have put in some `System.out.println("")'s` to check where I'm reaching in the file and for some reason Im only making it to the `addPlaylist() GUI`. I've tried debugging it and finding the error but I cannot find it!

This file is being called from the `main GUI` - I know that the database has values in it and that the connection is working because I've used it in another file.

Here is my `addPlaylist.java`:

```
package GUI;

import DBconnection.connection;


import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
public class addPlaylist extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private Container mainCon = this.getContentPane();
    private JPanel formPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel paidPanel = new JPanel();

    /*ALL USER INPUT FIELDS*************************/
    //Buttons
    private static JButton submitPlaylist = new JButton("Add Playlist");

    /*TEXT FIELDS BOXES *******************************/
    private JLabel lblPlaylistName = new JLabel("Playlist Name: ");
    private JTextField txtPlaylistName = new JTextField("", 15);
    /*TEXT FIELDS BOXES *******************************/

    /*COMBO BOXES *******************************/
    private JLabel lblNames = new JLabel();
    private JComboBox comNames = new JComboBox();
    /*COMBO BOXES *******************************/

    /*DECLARED VARIABLES ****************************/
    //    private String membersData = "";
    /*DECLARED VARIABLES ****************************/

    public addPlaylist(){
        super("Add a Playlist");
        this.setBounds(400, 500, 315,400);
        mainCon.add(formPanel);

        /** BEGINNING OF FORM ************/
        formPanel.add(lblPlaylistName);
        formPanel.add(txtPlaylistName);

        //Combobox (Names)
        formPanel.add(lblNames);
        formPanel.add(comNames);
        //comNames.addActionListener(this);

        //txtPlaylistName.addActionListener(this);
        System.out.println("In add playlist");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
        System.out.println("In Action Performed");
        /**ADD DATABASE CONNECTIONS*****************/
        /****** Set the default code - needed for SQL statements *************/
        Connection conDB = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet membersData = null;

        /** GET MYSQL DETAILs ---------**/
        String url = connection.geturl();
        String username = connection.getUsername();
        String password = connection.getPassword();


        try{
            System.out.println("In Try Statement");
             /****** DEFAULT MYSQL DRIVERS **************************/
            //load the MYSQL driver
                Class.forName(connection.getDriver());
                conDB = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                //create statement
                stmt = conDB.createStatement();
            /****** DEFAULT MYSQL DRIVERS **************************/

            String sqlSelect = "SELECT membId, name, memberType FROM members";
            membersData = stmt.executeQuery(sqlSelect);
            System.out.println("After executed");


            while(membersData.next()){
//                comNames.addItem(membersData.getString("name"));
                System.out.println("In while loop");
                String membId = membersData.getString("membId");
                System.out.println(membId);

     //            System.out.println(membersData.getString("name"));
     //            System.out.println(membersData.getString("memberType"));
            }
            //membersData.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException er){
            System.out.println("Error was: " + er);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("SECOND ERROR: " + ex);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: You need to have an action listener for your JFrame
Have the action listener of your button in the addPlaylist() contructor
 -> ( submitPlaylist .addActionListener(this); )

Comment: @Praveen - I've added an answer. By any chance would you know why my `JComboBox` has two of it's items checked? There are two copys of each item and if you click on one then the other becomes ticked?!

Comment: Have an ItemListener for the JComboBox 1 and update the next one whenever the first one is getting updated.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help :) @Praveen - But I realised that in the Database I had 2 of the same records in there :S For some reason everytime you clicked on one record that has the same name as another it also ticked the other one as well!

Answer (score 0):

So to fix this issue what I did was put all the code needed to display the `Combo box` include the `Database connections and result sets etc...` in a function called `showCombo()`. I then called `showCombo()` inside the `addPlaylist() { }` method.

Like so:

```
public void showCombo(){
            /****** Set the default code - needed for SQL statements *************/
        Connection conDB = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet membersData = null;



        /** GET MYSQL DETAILs ---------**/
        String url = connection.geturl();
        String username = connection.getUsername();
        String password = connection.getPassword();


        try{
            System.out.println("In Try Statement");
             /****** DEFAULT MYSQL DRIVERS **************************/
            //load the MYSQL driver
                Class.forName(connection.getDriver());
                conDB = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                //create statement
                stmt = conDB.createStatement();
            /****** DEFAULT MYSQL DRIVERS **************************/

            String sqlSelect = "SELECT membId, name, memberType FROM members";
            membersData = stmt.executeQuery(sqlSelect);
            System.out.println("After executed");



            while(membersData.next()){
                comNames.addItem(membersData.getString("name"));
//                System.out.println("In while loop");
//                String membId = membersData.getString("membId");
//                System.out.println(membId);

//                System.out.println(membersData.getString("name"));
//                System.out.println(membersData.getString("memberType"));
            }
            //membersData.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException er){
            System.out.println("Error was: " + er);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("SECOND ERROR: " + ex);
        }
        }
```